# Magento global notification not showing after upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, global-messages

After the upgrade to Magento to 1.9.2.0 the global message block is not shown anymore. The block is called in the template.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Where do you include the child block (e.g. in which template)? Do you have block-level-caching somewhere? You can try to see if the message-block is cached e.g. with Aoe_AdvancedTemplateHints https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints )

Comment: i didn't change anything. updated the magento version and messages are not showing on any page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was with the cache.i was using the third party extension and removing that the problem will be solved. the extension is not support the 1.9 version..